# MySQL выборка всех тегов пользователя с обозначением к какому типу увлечений он относится

Tags: php, mysql

Есть три таблицы

связующая таблица

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tags_map` (
  `ID` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `OBJECT_ID` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `TAG_ID` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `OBJECT_TYPE` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `CHILD_OBJECT` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  KEY `ID` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=190 ;
```

список тегов

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tags_list` (
  `ID` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `TAG` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `ID` (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `TAG` (`TAG`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=495 ;
```

пользователи

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_list` (
  `ID` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `USER_ID` int(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `USER_CODE` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `FILMS` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `GAME` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `TRAVEL` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `MUSIC` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `HOBBI` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `SPORT` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `JOB` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `BOOK` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `NAME` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `SURNAME` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `EDIT_DATE` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  UNIQUE KEY `ID` (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `USER_ID` (`USER_ID`,`EMAIL`),
  UNIQUE KEY `EMAIL` (`EMAIL`),
  KEY `FAMILY_STATUS` (`FAMILY_STATUS`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=13 ;
```

Хочу запросов вывести все теги пользователя с указанием к какому типу относятся (OBJECT_TYPE)

---

Запрос выводит одну запись

```
SELECT tl.*, tm.* FROM tags_map tm, user_list ul, tags_list tl WHERE tm.OBJECT_TYPE = '$object_type' AND tm.OBJECT_ID = $object_id GROUP BY tl.ID AND tm.ID
```

запрос выводит все теги но помечает что все они типа MUSIC, тоесть взяв данные из таблицы tags_map продолжает их использовать для каждого результата

```
SELECT tl.*, tm.* FROM tags_map tm, user_list ul, tags_list tl WHERE tm.OBJECT_TYPE = '$object_type' AND tm.OBJECT_ID = $object_id GROUP BY tl.ID
```

Помогите построить правильный запрос :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не связали таблицы в запросе, у вас декартово произведение, которое вы замаскировали с помощью `group by`, и удивляетесь тому, что данные возвращаются не верные. Если я правильно понимаю, `tags_map.object_id = user_list.id`, так? В противном случае поменяйте связи на то, что нужно:

```
select ul.`name`, tl.`tag`
from `tags_map` tm
  join `user_list` ul on tm.`object_id` = ul.`id`
  join `tags_list` tl on tm.`tag_id` = tl.`id`
where
  tm.`object_id` = 1 
  and tm.`object_type` = 'not music'
```

Запрос следует читать так: Для каждого тэгмэпа берем описание юзера, берем описание тэга и ограничиваем выборку по id объекта (юзеру) и по типу тэга.

Теперь по структуре. У вас в таблицах не заданы первичные ключи. Хорошо, что есть уникальные, но первичные нужны обязательно. Первичный ключ - идентификатор записи, он является также уникальным и создает кластерный индекс (записи упорядочены физически в соответствии с ним), что работает в общем случае быстрее, чем некластерный индекс.

Далее. Для развязочной таблицы необходимы индексы. Конкретно для данного запроса:

- составной (`object_id`, `object_type`), слабое звено - строковый object_type.
- учитывая `varchar` для `object_type`, лучше может оказаться индекс просто по `object_id`. он будет и меньше и быстрее, скорее всего.